# I'd like to join the chorus of complainnig about off topic closures

Tags: discussion, specific-question

While I am not too worried because I actually got my question answered (and accepted the answer), I would still like to think that I understand enough about the subject matter that this site deals with and that [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83595/is-this-hamas-military-uniform), even in its original form, was on topic.

Military uniform standardization by governments is about as much as it gets when it comes to learning about inner workings of government.

I get that some people think something was being implied that they don't like in the original wording.  In fact, it was that wording (with a slight logical fallacy and, therefore, an opportunity to correct it) that solicited a very good answer, so I think it did the job.  But I clarified it for the sake of pedantic purity.  Hardly anyone should suspect me of being in tank for Hamas if they look through my history of questions/answers.

[rant]Ok, they might get wrong idea from my insisting that Hamas is a de jure signatory of the Geneva Conventions, but I usually bring that up to point out that they have a responsibility to abide by them (which they clearly do not do), but, of course, that also means that they are protected by the conventions as bad-faith signatories [/rant].

But that's besides the point.  The point is that when questions which are so wildly on topic get closed as off-topic, that just sends the wrong message to anyone trying to learn what the topic of this site is by casually looking through the content.  I know what it is.  You probably know what it is because you are reading this meta post.

But a more casual user who sees that question having been closed as "off-topic" will get a very wrong idea.

P.S. I get the downvotes...  and honestly, given the original wording, they just warm my heart.  But not the "off-topic" closure.  We should be mindful of the fact that they do more than just treat 1 question.  They provide future guidance.

Comment: I'd like to join the chorus of people complaining about the non-existence of a chorus of people complaining about off-topic closures being used to exaggerate regular disgruntlement at posts being curated and moderated against individual opinions.

Comment: @Nij sorry, to many levels of negatives.  I honestly cannot say if you are mocking me or agreeing with me.  I am ok with either.  But, please, simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the reason why your question was closed:

> The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the help center.

Basically, some members of the community believe you are using this platform to spread some propaganda. And so they have voted to close your question. Some other members, with their own different political bias, will then vote to reopen the question, and may succeed. Then the others will again vote to close or delete or even make a post here, like you, complaining to the moderators who may act, depending on their moods and according to their own political biases.

**Realistically, you can't do much about it** - this is the current system on the platform and that is how it works. (It's "fair" in that you can vote and take the same actions too).

But it is not a perfect system. As you and others have observed, the major flaw of the current system is that it is based on the idea of benevolent dictators (the moderators) and majoritarian democracy. Thus, *there is currently no way to insulate the system from the political biases of its community members.* (A very good example of this in action was observed by me when my question here in Meta, on a moderation / review suggestion, itself was deleted - https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6648/45056 - probably because my suggestion to the political content it referred to "offended" some here).

One simple idea I have suggested before is to **increase the number of votes to close or delete a question**. This will make it more difficult for a small number of members to manipulate the voting system. This community has grown, and so the diversity of political opinions here are likely to increase and cause this kind of minor disagreements. As such, it is in the interest of the community to allow these diverse opinions, and in the interest of the reviewers to prevent the same questions from re-appearing in moderation queues again and again, because of the close-reopen votes.

**Note**: When I say the number of votes to close or delete a question should be increased, I meant only for the particular option we are discussing - *The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause* ... The other reasons to close a question are more **objective** ("A community-specific reason", "Needs details or clarity", "Needs more focus", "Opinion-based", "Duplicate etc.) and thus can be reasonably understood or challenged. And thus cannot be so easily abused. But the "propaganda" option is a very *subjective* one - we can find "propaganda" in any of the questions here, and one can even make a decent argument for it. Such subjective options should thus necessarily need a higher amount of votes to get activated.

Comment: I am not sure that increasing the threshold would make a big impact. The negativity tends to snowball. I don't think the moderators have tools to make it a variable, but it might help to tie the number of votes required to close a question to the number of upvotes it has. Maybe something like 4+X, where X is the number of upvotes divided by 5. So a +20/-15 question would require 4+4=8 VTC to close and so would a +20/-25 question. I don't know if numbers can change attitudes though. If someone sees a topic that frustrates them, I think they should think twice about VTC if the Q is +30.

Comment: Looking at the question you linked and it doesn't appear that a user deleted it and instead it was automatically deleted by the system based on criteria that have been set.  "This post is hidden. It was automatically deleted 4 days ago by CommunityBot."

Comment: @JoeW If I remember right, SE provides an option for some reviewer / moderator actions to be anonymous - in such cases one of the options given is whether you want to tag a message with your user name or with "communityBot". Even if it was done by the "system", the lack of transparency doesn't really help - Do you personally think that there is something wrong with that Q and that Meta wasn't the right place for it? I don't even understand why it was downvoted at all - when we reviewers / moderators don't even bother to be helpful amongst us, that itself is telling about a community.

Comment: That is only for things such as adding a comment to a question as part of a review. However if you go look at the review itself you can see who left that comment. There is no way for an action to be completely anonymous. Deleting a question will always state exactly who did it. Your question was automatically deleted by the system based on advertised criteria. https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions

Comment: @JoeW That is why I mentioned the downvotes and the lack of transparency too - there are some who manipulate the system in bad faith. The Q got downvoted to oblivion - all for a simple suggestion that two Qs on anti-Semitism be merged (and as a plus it would encourage a new member to keep participating). The only conclusion I make from this is that some here wanted one of those Qs closed or deleted. In other words, it wasn't merit of review or moderation that decided what happened, but the politics of the subject. (Which is why I cited that Q as an example of the community politics here too).

Comment: What lack of transparency? People didn't agree with your question and the automated system took action based on that. It seems that you are equating not agreeing with how others see your question as a lack of transparency. Also there isn't a need to argue with me over how the system works as I am just pointing out why your question got deleted and that it wasn't a person taking action on it.

Comment: @JoeW The upvotes and downvotes are not for "agreeing" or "disagreeing" with a Q. It is to highlight a good question or to suggest that the question needs improvement. If members downvote a Q or A, it's expected that they atleast leave a comment on how the Q can be improved or point out issues on it (JJJ had the courtesy to do that). The rest of the downvoters didn't as they weren't acting in good faith and wanted the Q buried. I am not arguing with you - I understand you are just offering me a different perspective that seems more reasonable to you, and I am sharing my own views on it too.

Comment: The hint on the downvote button is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" and on meta it is also used to signal disagreement with the question. Just because you think it is a good question doesn't mean that others will agree with you. And you shouldn't be accusing people of not acting in good faith which means you are accusing them of acting in bad faith when you don't know who down voted or why they did.

Comment: @Joew That's what I meant by "lack of transparency" - if the downvoters or close-delete voters don't explain themselves, how does it help anyone?

Comment: Again, that isn't a lack of transparency. In fact people are discouraged from explaining the reasons for downvoting on a question because there are users who will retaliate for downvotes by downvoting those users content. If people did not take these types of actions more people would be willing to discuss their reasons. In fact I would say your constant chain of comments at me is proof of why people don't explain these votes. All I did was point out that your question got deleted by the system with no user action and you keep wanting to convince me that the system is wrong.

Comment: I would like to point out that this comment thread is making me regret pointing out the real reason for your question getting deleted in the first place and without that it is unlikely you would have gotten any feedback on it at all. Remember how people providing that feedback feel even if you don't agree with it.

Comment: @JoeW That's just due to the nature of this platform - the lack of verbal cues in a comment can make it look like we both are arguing, where as I actually found your views helpful *even if I don't agree with it* just as I hope you better understand my point of view - I obviously make an effort to offer clarification on most downvotes and close-delete votes I do, without caring about the repercussion because I believe transparency helps the community (and I have faced repercussions from disgruntled users, like you said. I just ignore it as an immature attitude). Thanks for your patience.

Comment: And given the fact that I have no control over the fact that voting on questions is anonymous and that people are not required to leave a comment when down voting, voting to close or voting to delete why do you feel the need to keep questioning me about all of this? You keep asking me about all the supposed lack of transparency even though I have no control or say in that matter. In fact you keep showing over and over again why people don't leave comments on threads when they do any of those actions because the person they are pointing out could easily refuse to accept the fact

Comment: You repeated comments show yet again that you refuse to accept the fact that we have different opinions on these things and keep wanting to change my mind on it even though what I think about it has no control on how the system works or how other people act within those rules. It might just be a good idea to accept that fact and either post a question asking for changes or just move on. Trying to debate me about this over and over again isn't going to change anything when I am just pointing out how the system works

Comment: @JoeW As I have explained repeatedly here - I am not attacking you or questioning you or having a debate or an argument with you! You shared your point of views, which I appreciate and found helpful, and I have shared mine too in return. I wasn't trying to convince you of anything and was just explaining *how I perceived the whole thing* so that we understand each other better. We do not have to necessarily agree with each others view to do that.

Comment: I never said you are attacking me, but you keep replying to me in chat explaining why you think things that I have no control about are wrong. There is no reason to keep pinging people who have no control over something that you disagree with. If you disagree that strongly with how the voting system and explaining votes works you should be posting a question on this meta or the main meta not trying to explain it to someone who has no control or care about the matter

Comment: In the end I posted a comment to try and help you understand what happened to your question, not to get a long continuing explanation of why you think the current system is wrong and needs to change.

Comment: @JoeW *but you keep replying to me in chat explaining ... There is no reason to keep pinging people who have no control over something that you disagree with.* Ok, I understand your PoV better now. I thought you would be interested to know my perspectives too, where as you just wanted to state some view of yours publicly without necessarily engaging in a conversation on it. The next time I disagree or have a different point of view to yours, I will post it without pinging you so that you do not feel forced to talk to me.

Comment: Yes, because I am trying to explain to you why people don't leave explanations for their actions is in part because the person they are leaving it for won't let it go. You keep responding to me in order to explain why you think the system is broken even though all I did was point out how the system works and I have zero control over it. Please stop pinging me to try and explain why you think things are wrong and how it should worlk

Comment: re you last edit, I don't 1 reason for closure can be valued less than others.  The reasons for closing questions serve as commentary on the votes.  If a vote succeeds, then the most frequent reason is made available. But many questions get close votes with multiple reasons being given as the reason for closing.

Comment: @wrod That's a good point I hadn't considered.